# How is Universe expansion measured with CMB

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

There are plenty of articles about measuring the universe with standard candles, parallax, certain types of stars, etc. CMB measurements are usually introduced into the article to bring attention to the discrepancy or tension between the two. They usually spend time describing how the standard candle/parallax measurements are derived but not so much with the CMB. 
Question: is there a simple description of how CMB measurements translate into expansion rate?

Comment: look at the answer here  https://www.quora.com/How-is-Hubble-constant-calculated-from-Cosmic-Microwave-Background-Radiation-measurements

Comment: @annav thank you

Comment: I’m still not quite getting it. Are there any other good examples? It seems iffy with assumptions but I realize it’s held to a high standard, therefore I’m missing something. Thanks

Comment: But it is iffy with assumptions. It cosmologial model dependent.

Comment: @annav OK but still I can follow the parallax/standard candle method of measuring distances but I’m having a hard time seeing what you’re doing here with the CMB. Can you generalize what you’re actually doing?

Comment: The answer is by a cosmologist, and the distance/time enters through a fit to the curves shown, so it depends on a lot of assumptions about the previous to the CMB time evolution.  So the CMB number is very model dependent. I would use the discrepancy with  the other methods  to correct the assumptions in the model, i.e. take the Hubble constant as given by the other data and try to improve the assumptions in the cosmological model.

Comment: “*use the discrepancy with the other methods to correct the assumptions in the model*” - This is exactly correct, but the problem is that no tweaking is enough. You have to drop the entire FLRW cosmological model to make the tension disappear. And once you do, the universe is no longer accelerating and there is no unobserved “dark energy”.  Beautiful!